# Firefox can't draw an image with a data uri onto a canvas: NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE

Tags: javascript, firefox, canvas, html5-canvas

I've got an SVG data uri successfully rendering to an img element in my page. In Chrome, using `drawImage` to draw the image onto a canvas works perfectly, but in FireFox, I get NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE.

Here's a fiddle that works in Chrome but not Firefox. Click the button to trigger the copy.

http://jsfiddle.net/YbA39/181/

Are there any workarounds or other ways to convince firefox to draw this image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer seems to be that it's a bug in Firefox at the moment, specifically relating to SVG's: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=700533

Firefox's own documentation says it should work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#drawImage()

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I guess here, is when the resources be available?, but there is a way to confirm that the resources are available, just check 'complete' attribute of the image object.

```
if (img.complete == true){
   // is available.
} else {
   // wait until is ready.
}
```

Also, you can make a merge method with onload event and a delay method that checking both stuff.

```
var img = new Image();
//first attach handler
img.onload = function(e){
   if (e.target.complete == true) {
            yourHandler(e);
        } else {               
            var maxTimes = 10;
            var countTimes = 0;
            function retryLoadImage() {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    if (countTimes > maxTimes) {
                        // -- cannot load image.
                        return;
                    } else {
                        if (e.target.complete == true) {
                            yourHandler(e);
                        } else {
                            retryLoadImage();
                        }
                    }
                    countTimes++;
                }, 50);
            }; 
        }
};
img.src = yourSource;
```

This is working for me!!! on IE and FF.

Answer (score -1):

add `try catch`

```
try {
   ctx.drawImage(blah, 0, 0, 200, 200);
        } catch(err) {}
```

this below link says there is a way-around on this.

http://www.jason-palmer.com/2009/03/mooflow-firefox-uncaught-exception-fix/

Comment: This solution only silences the error. As per the link you provided: "Note: this “fix” will disable [the feature] in the firefox browser".